# Homing X and Y after stopping print through display

Tags: marlin, firmware

How can I include homing X and Y  of a Marlin firmware operating printer after I press the stop printing in the display?

In which folder I need include the command?

Answer (score 1):

It's `EVENT_GCODE_SD_STOP` in the `configuration_adv.h` [file](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h#L1050).

It appears to have been [added to Marlin 2.0.x on 2019-04-03](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/pull/13547/commits/2dc6b58c230a8fb5a307a82f83e2080de84d0f49).

Comment: Maybe you can expand the answer, to include whether it is possible to include the command(s) in a file as stated in the question.